# execute beamer goto button with a wireless pointer?

Tags: beamer, navigation, pointer

I'm giving a beamer presentation that relies heavily on beamergotobutton and beamerreturnbutton.    Normally I present with a logitech presenter remote pointer, but it doesn't appear to allow me to remotely point and click on a button.   I imagine this technology must exist, but have been unable to find anything about  it on the web.

Could somebody please advise?

Comment: This sounds like a Logitech and/or viewer issue. Does it work with other links in other PDFs

Comment: I use a Targus pointer. It has two modes: pointer and mouse. As mouse I can "press" on goto buttons but I cannot do it working as pointer.

Comment: Thanks @Ignasi!   I've just ordered a Targus Multimedia Presentation Remote.   Guess I'll have to carry two at once!      Seems like they could integrate the two functions...